# Long wait time before failed connection to Tibco EMS

Tags: .net-core, tibco, tibco-ems

I am testing how my code handles situation when machine doesn't have connection to TIBCO Server. I'm using TIBCO.EMS.dll version 8.5.0.5.
I don't understand why with these settings it takes around 4 minutes 25 seconds to receive error.

```
_factory = new ConnectionFactory(URL);
_factory.SetConnAttemptCount(2);
//_factory.SetConnAttemptTimeout(1000);
_factory.SetConnAttemptDelay(1000);
_factory.SetReconnAttemptCount(2);
_factory.SetReconnAttemptDelay(1000);
//_factory.SetReconnAttemptTimeout(1000);
var conn = _factory.CreateConnection(username, password);
```

The error is:
`Failed to connect to the server at...`. I am using tcp connection. Shouldn't it be maximum 2 x 1000ms (plus some delay between attempts)?

When I uncomment the timeout settings in code above I receive different error:
`Failed to initialize connection before timeout`. Also after around 4 minutes 25 seconds.

This code is executed at service startup so I would prefer it to fail fast as it delays startup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a connection factory already defined in the target EMS server this is possible for the factory to be configured with none default connection / reconnection parameters.

From tibemsadmin you can use the show factory  command to check if some specific values have been set.

See an example below:

```
show factory "QueueConnectionFactory"
Factory                     = QueueConnectionFactory
JNDI Names                  = "QueueConnectionFactory"
URL                         = tcp://7222
ClientID                    =
Load Balanced               = no
connect_attempt_count       = 6
connect_attempt_delay       = 10000
connect_attempt_timeout     = 1000
reconnect_attempt_count     = 12
reconnect_attempt_delay     = 10000
reconnect_attempt_timeout   = 1000
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to use connection factory configured in EMS server when using .NET. I'm building my own factory and configure it.

Comment: I'am not sure how things are working while using the .NET API. I have noticed that in some cases it takes more time for a connection to fail than expected. Is there a connection to an EMS server before the creation of the Factory ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I create factory to create connection to EMS server.

Comment: When using a connection factory defined at server level you first connect to the EMS server having the connection factory definition and then in a second step connect to the EMS server defined in the factory (in that case you have two connections). It seems this doesn't apply in your context where the client creates its own factory.